# Create a LXD-based Juju controller that works with physical MAAS

Tags: juju, maas, lxd

I have a MAAS setup with 5 servers, including the region controller.

Can I create a LXD-based Juju controller that works with the physical MAAS?

I lose a machine for the Juju controller each time I deploy. Is there some way to keep my 4 physical servers for Juju charms?

Comment: Virtme juju charms seem's to be the solution :) better idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last night mi solution has make a Juju LXD Controler in the MAAS server and "add-machine ssh:node.maas" for every node...

The bad one is the auto creation of new LXD machines when a bundle-charm is deploy, i use de --to X to point to de phisical PC and add-unit --to X to have redundancy.

I have four nodes 2 on trusty and 2 on xenial, for some charms.
But in general i think is working good, today start OpenStack in this cloud!

Answer (score 2):

Juju 2.0 supports multiple models within a single controller.

Also, with MAAS, you can deploy charms into LXD containers on the physical machines.

Answer (score 1):

For every cloud (this includes MAAS), Juju will use up (dedicate) a machine in that cloud for the "Juju controller".

The virtme charm looks unmaintained. I wouldn't use it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this with MAAS is by adding a virtual machine on the MAAS controller to run the Juju controller. Create a virtual machine in virsh and then add that virtual machine to MAAS. You can then bootstrap Juju on the virtual machine. This gives you the ability to use Juju with MAAS without losing a physical machine.